# Multiplying values in Impala query

Tags: sql, math, impala

I am trying to multiply values in impala.  Below is my statement and attached is a screenshot of the resulting output.  The calculation works for some rows and returns a NULL for others.

```
SELECT
 a.bom_number
,a.plant
,a.component_assembly_bom_material_number
,a.bom_component_material_number
,a.level
,a.Assembly_Flag
,a.level_1_inclusion
,a.level_2_inclusion
,a.level_3_inclusion
,a.level_4_inclusion
,a.level_5_inclusion
,a.level_6_inclusion
,a.level_7_inclusion
,a.level_8_inclusion
,a.level_9_inclusion
,a.level_10_inclusion
,coalesce(
a.level_1_inclusion * 
a.level_2_inclusion * 
a.level_4_inclusion * 
a.level_5_inclusion * 
a.level_6_inclusion *
a.level_7_inclusion *
a.level_8_inclusion *
a.level_9_inclusion *
a.level_10_inclusion ,1) Final
FROM tmp_levels a
```

```
[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5ryS.png)
```

[image: output]

Values would multiply correctly across all rows

Comment: For starters, you're missing `level_3_inclusion` from the multiplication. Then it's returning null when it's multiplying all 1's. Does your data require a `coalesce`?

Comment: If any of the columns you are multiplying are null, the result will be null.  You need to coalesce each column with 1, not the entire thing.

Comment: When you multiply two columns, if one of them is null, result will be null...

Answer (score 0):

Using some dummy data:

```
create table #test
(
    one int,
    two int,
    three int,
    four int,
    five int
)

insert into #test values
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
(1, null, 2, 3, 4),
(1, 2, null, 3, null),
(null, null, null, null, null)
```

This illustrates some options, depending on how you want to handle the missing values (which isn't clear from your question):

```
select
    one, two, three, four, five,
    one * two * three * four * five as rawOutput,
    coalesce(one * two * three * four * five, 1) as badCoalesce,
    isnull(one, 1) * isnull(two, 1) * isnull(three, 1) * isnull(four, 1) * isnull(five, 1) as betterCoalesce,
    case 
        when coalesce(one, two, three, four, five) is null 
        then null 
        else isnull(one, 1) * isnull(two, 1) * isnull(three, 1) * isnull(four, 1) * isnull(five, 1) 
    end as handleAllNull
from #test
```

Results:

| one | two | three | four | five | rawOutput | badCoalesce | betterCoalesce | handleAllNull |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 120 | 120 | 120 | 120 |
| 1 | NULL | 2 | 3 | 4 | NULL | 1 | 24 | 24 |
| 1 | 2 | NULL | 3 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 6 | 6 |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL |